# Re install Terraria on new laptop

Tags: terraria

I already installed Terraria on a laptop. I got a newer laptop and i want to re install on this new laptop.
How can i remove from my old and installed on my new laptop?

thanks

Comment: Since you already installed it once can you not repeat the steps you did the first time?

Comment: @Colin I don't think they want to pay for it again

Comment: Is it with Steam, GoG, or another installer? Just wondering, as the steam method is below and the save files are in your "Documents"\My Games\Terraria folder by default.  GoG gives you an installer file that can be installed anywhere, and to remove just use add/remove programs.

Answer (score 2):

Download Steam from this link - http://store.steampowered.com/about/

Run the file you downloaded.  Log in using an existing account and enter your username and password for Steam.  You may need to go to your email and enter a security code due to you logging onto Steam on a new computer.

After you log onto Steam, go to your Library and click the dark entry on the left labeled Terraria.  Once you are on that page, click the blue Install button on the right panel.  Keep clicking next.  Terraria will automagically and install.

If you want to remove Terraria on your old laptop, go to Steam on that computer.  Right click on the entry Terraria in your Library, and select the option Delete Local Content.  Keep clicking next.  After you click finish, it will delete all Terraria's files from your computer.

Comment: Keep in mind that you don't *have* to remove it from the old laptop for this to work.

Comment: You can even copy the game files from an old laptop which should be find at "..\Steam\SteamApps\common\terraria\" and copy it to the new one in the "common" folder after steam installation. So no need to download Terraria again.

Comment: True, but why not set it up automagically?  And the OP did ask to uninstall it from their old laptop.